# Wrong position of glyphicon in HTML?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3, glyphicons

How can I get the Glyphicon to show up on the same row and left to the links, and not over the link as it does now? Whitout the glyphicon becoming a part of the link?

Here is the code:

```
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span>
<a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/" target="_blank">
    <h4><b>Some website</b></h4>
</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This syntax should get you what you are looking for:

```
<h4><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-exclamation-sign"></span><a href="http://www.somewebsite.com/" target="_blank"> Some website</a></h4>
```

From the Twitter Bootstrap documentation talking about Glyphicons, it reads there to add a nested span tag and apply the icon classes to the span tag. Here's a link to the Twitter Bootstrap documentation on Glyphicons: [Twitter Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/components/)

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you added the css styles already in effect to the question.

But in general, if the glyphicon is covering the link, you could add left margin to the link. The margin part wont be clickable.

Comment: This is not how to use bootstrap, as the default CSS covers this already. See khilley's answer.